# how to develop a node.js app which supports multitenancies

Tags: node.js

I have a requirement that I want to serve multiple sites(host names) with the same port number.

These sites share the same code files, while only differ in that they have different site configurations and file upload folders.

basically it's just a cms which can host various domains, and usually each domain will have its own themes and configurations and of course db connections.

is there anybody who can give me some directions on this? Thanks very
much.

Comment: What direction/help do you specifically need?  What you describe is certainly possible but you'll get better guidance if you ask for specific details.

Comment: well, i'm developing a cms application with node.js, i would like this cms app to be able to serve different domain names, however each domain will have its own template files and db connection, etc.

Comment: Use a proxy like [node-http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy)

Answer (score 2):

```
var subdomains = require('express-subdomains')
    , express = require('express')
    , app = Express.createServer()

// example: api.example.com/user -> '/api/user'

subdomains
  .use('api')
  .use('other.vanity.domain')

app.use(subdomains.middleware)

app.get('/api/user' function (req, res, next) {
  // ..
})

app.listen()
```

https://github.com/tblobaum/express-subdomains

Comment: Just out of curiousity, does this work for hosts of this format `http://mypage.mysite.superhost.ext/`?

Comment: this will look in req.headers.host so it will match both vanity domains and subdomains

Answer (score 1):

Each site should have it's own process and port, and you should proxy requests depending on the hostname.

You can use [node-http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy) or [bouncy](https://github.com/substack/bouncy) for proxy each site to its specific port. Another option is to use Express's vhost feature: https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/examples/vhost/app.js

Comment: vhost feature looks promising in this regard

Comment: yes indeed, however my advice is to use node-http-proxy or bouncy, since it's better to have separated processes so you can monitor them individually etc, it's better that way.

Comment: i think it's pretty much similar to using nginx as a reverse proxy server, which might be simpler to monitor

Comment: Yes that's true, Nginx is a valid solution here also, but it's trickier when using WebSockets, that's why I recommended these two.

Comment: yeah, that's great, and I found people tend to use web socket to build real time apps with node.js

Answer (score 1):

You can easily support multiple domains from a single HTTP server codebase (see [virtual hosting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting)), you will just need to implement logic in your handlers to inspect the request host (e.g. in the `Host` HTTP header) and act conditionally based on its value.  Then you can have any number of DNS names point to your server and act differently on them.

Here's an example:

```javascript
http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  var host = request.headers['Host'];
  if (host == 'domain1.com') {
    // Execute logic based on that host.
  } else if (host == 'domain2.com') {
    // Execute other logic...
  }
}).listen(8080);
```